# GNUplot concatenate 2 macros in an xlabel

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to concatenate two string macros, each with a different font into a single xlabel?

```
xLabel1="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
style1=" offset 0,2 font \"Gill Sans,12\""
xLabel2="\"A\" font \"Moon Phases,28\" offset 0,2"
label1="xLabel1 @style1"
label2="xLabel2"
bothLabels="@label1 @label2"
```

Both label1 and label2 work when used alone for the xlabel.
It's the last line that I cannot figure out; perhaps this cannot be done?
"A" in that font displays a full moon symbol.

Comment: What gnuplot version?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any problem nesting more than one macro inside a string.

```
set macro
SET='set '
LABEL='label 1 @WHAT @WHERE'
WHAT="'bar' "
WHERE="at 0,1 front"
ALL=SET.LABEL
@ALL
show label
```

However, at this point, I would also recommend using `eval` and `sprintf`.

Comment: GNUplot 4.6.1 on OSX 10.6.8